# Do "point of accumulation" and "boundary point" mean the same thing?

Tags: general-topology

In my text it says, if a set $\Omega$ contains all points of accumulation $\{c\}$, then $\Omega$ is closed. I was surprised because people usually use "boundary point" in this context.

And further defines points of accumulation as: $c$ is a *point of accumulation* for $\mathbb{K}$ if every neighborhood of $c$ contains at least one point of $\mathbb{K}$ distinct from $c$.

Comment: What text, exactly, says this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A accumulation point could be in the interior of a set, hence not in the boundary.

Comment: So it is the superset of boundary points? So the text is being more relaxed with definition of a closed set?

Comment: No, for example consider the open interval plus a point: $]0,1[\cup\{2\}$. Then its accumulation is $[0,1]$ and its boundary $\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: What do you mean to be more relaxed?

Comment: Relaxed meaning that having points of accumulation is a sufficient but not necessary condition for a set to be a closed set

Comment: A set is closed if and only if contains all its accumulation points

Answer (score 0):

The boundary $\partial(S)$ of a set $S$ is defined as $\bar{S} \cap \bar{S^c}$. So if $x \in \partial(S)$ then $x$ is an accumulation point.

However, $x$ does not have to be on the boundary to be an accumulation point.

Comment: But can't a boundary point be an isolated point?

Comment: there could be points for a set that are in the boundary but not being accumulation ones

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it is false. A boundary point is not necessarily an accumulation. Take A={5} as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then its boundary agrees with A, while the set of its accumulation points is empty.